# Java Selenium, how to directly define/modify javascript function and run it in browser?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, selenium

A little bit of background here... In my school there is an online poll among different dorms, and the dorm that get the most votes will get a special prize. The poll seemed innocent at first, but it quickly turned into a coding competition. I am quite familiar with java and was able to use Selenium Chromedriver to autoclick buttons, refresh the browser, and clear cookies. This allows the program to vote about 1 or 2 votes per second. However, when I delved into the HTML script of the website, I am wondering if there is a quicker way to achieve my goal. Instead of clicking the button directly, why not call its "onclick" javascript function, or even modify it? That way, there is no need to refresh browser, clear cookie, or even search for HTML webElements... The poll is structured like this:

```
<form id="polls_form_30" class="wp-polls-form" action="/index.php"      method="post">
    <p style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" id="poll_30_nonce" name="wp-polls-nonce" value="1aee40712a" /></p>
    <p style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" name="poll_id" value="30" /></p>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>What's the Best Dorm? </strong></p><div id="polls-30-ans" class="wp-polls-ans"><ul class="wp-polls-ul">
    <li><input type="radio" id="poll-answer-112" name="poll_30" value="112" /> <label for="poll-answer-112">Connell</label></li>
    <li><input type="radio" id="poll-answer-113" name="poll_30" value="113" /> <label for="poll-answer-113">Dahl</label></li>
    /*The other options are not shown*/
    </ul><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="button" name="vote" value="   Vote   " class="Buttons" onclick="poll_vote(30);" />
```

Searching for the poll_vote() functions, I found the source code:

```
var poll_id = 0;
var poll_answer_id = '';
var is_being_voted = false;
pollsL10n.show_loading = parseInt(pollsL10n.show_loading);
pollsL10n.show_fading = parseInt(pollsL10n.show_fading);

// When User Vote For Poll
function poll_vote(current_poll_id) {
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if(!is_being_voted) {
        set_is_being_voted(true);
        poll_id = current_poll_id;
        poll_answer_id = '';
        poll_multiple_ans = 0;
        poll_multiple_ans_count = 0;
        if($('#poll_multiple_ans_' + poll_id).length) {
            poll_multiple_ans = parseInt($('#poll_multiple_ans_' + poll_id).val());
        }
        $('#polls_form_' + poll_id + ' input:checkbox, #polls_form_' + poll_id + ' input:radio, #polls_form_' + poll_id + ' option').each(function(i){
            if ($(this).is(':checked') || $(this).is(':selected')) {
                if(poll_multiple_ans > 0) {
                    poll_answer_id = $(this).val() + ',' + poll_answer_id;
                    poll_multiple_ans_count++;
                } else {
                    poll_answer_id = parseInt($(this).val());
                }
            }
        });
        if(poll_multiple_ans > 0) {
            if(poll_multiple_ans_count > 0 && poll_multiple_ans_count <= poll_multiple_ans) {
                poll_answer_id = poll_answer_id.substring(0, (poll_answer_id.length-1));
                poll_process();
            } else if(poll_multiple_ans_count == 0) {
                set_is_being_voted(false);
                alert(pollsL10n.text_valid);
            } else {
                set_is_being_voted(false);
                alert(pollsL10n.text_multiple + ' ' + poll_multiple_ans);
            }
        } else {
            if(poll_answer_id > 0) {
                poll_process();
            } else {
                set_is_being_voted(false);
                alert(pollsL10n.text_valid);
            }
        }
    } else {
        alert(pollsL10n.text_wait);
    }
});
}

// Process Poll (User Click "Vote" Button)
function poll_process() {
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    poll_nonce = $('#poll_' + poll_id + '_nonce').val();
    if(pollsL10n.show_fading) {
        $('#polls-' + poll_id).fadeTo('def', 0);
        if(pollsL10n.show_loading) {
            $('#polls-' + poll_id + '-loading').show();
        }
        $.ajax({type: 'POST', xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}, url: pollsL10n.ajax_url, data: 'action=polls&view=process&poll_id=' + poll_id + '&poll_' + poll_id + '=' + poll_answer_id + '&poll_' + poll_id + '_nonce=' + poll_nonce, cache: false, success: poll_process_success});
    } else {
        if(pollsL10n.show_loading) {
            $('#polls-' + poll_id + '-loading').show();
        }
        $.ajax({type: 'POST', xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}, url: pollsL10n.ajax_url, data: 'action=polls&view=process&poll_id=' + poll_id + '&poll_' + poll_id + '=' + poll_answer_id + '&poll_' + poll_id + '_nonce=' + poll_nonce, cache: false, success: poll_process_success});
    }
});
}

// Poll's Result (User Click "View Results" Link)
function poll_result(current_poll_id) {
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if(!is_being_voted) {
        set_is_being_voted(true);
        poll_id = current_poll_id;
        poll_nonce = $('#poll_' + poll_id + '_nonce').val();
        if(pollsL10n.show_fading) {
            $('#polls-' + poll_id).fadeTo('def', 0);
            if(pollsL10n.show_loading) {
                $('#polls-' + poll_id + '-loading').show();
            }
            $.ajax({type: 'POST', xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}, url: pollsL10n.ajax_url, data: 'action=polls&view=result&poll_id=' + poll_id + '&poll_' + poll_id + '_nonce=' + poll_nonce, cache: false, success: poll_process_success});
        } else {
            if(pollsL10n.show_loading) {
                $('#polls-' + poll_id + '-loading').show();
            }
            $.ajax({type: 'POST', xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}, url: pollsL10n.ajax_url, data: 'action=polls&view=result&poll_id=' + poll_id + '&poll_' + poll_id + '_nonce=' + poll_nonce, cache: false, success: poll_process_success});
        }
    } else {
        alert(pollsL10n.text_wait);
    }
});
}

// Poll's Voting Booth  (User Click "Vote" Link)
function poll_booth(current_poll_id) {
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if(!is_being_voted) {
        set_is_being_voted(true);
        poll_id = current_poll_id;
        poll_nonce = $('#poll_' + poll_id + '_nonce').val();
        if(pollsL10n.show_fading) {
            $('#polls-' + poll_id).fadeTo('def', 0);
            if(pollsL10n.show_loading) {
                $('#polls-' + poll_id + '-loading').show();
            }
            $.ajax({type: 'POST', xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}, url: pollsL10n.ajax_url, data: 'action=polls&view=booth&poll_id=' + poll_id + '&poll_' + poll_id + '_nonce=' + poll_nonce, cache: false, success: poll_process_success});
        } else {
            if(pollsL10n.show_loading) {
                $('#polls-' + poll_id + '-loading').show();
            }
            $.ajax({type: 'POST', xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}, url: pollsL10n.ajax_url, data: 'action=polls&view=booth&poll_id=' + poll_id + '&poll_' + poll_id + '_nonce=' + poll_nonce, cache: false, success: poll_process_success});
        }
    } else {
        alert(pollsL10n.text_wait);
    }
});
}

// Poll Process Successfully
function poll_process_success(data) {
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#polls-' + poll_id).replaceWith(data);
    if(pollsL10n.show_loading) {
        $('#polls-' + poll_id + '-loading').hide();
    }
    if(pollsL10n.show_fading) {
        $('#polls-' + poll_id).fadeTo('def', 1);
        set_is_being_voted(false);
    } else {
        set_is_being_voted(false);
    }
});
}

// Set is_being_voted Status
function set_is_being_voted(voted_status) {
is_being_voted = voted_status;
}
```

https://github.com/lesterchan/wp-polls/blob/master/polls-js.dev.js

The problem is that first of all, I have no experience in javascript. My question is that how to modify this function such that all it does to pass the voting request to the poll results, and that it doesn't cause the browser to jump to another url?(Or in this case JQuery, I guess)The spamming program can be even more efficient if this function doesn't change cookie in my browser. Is it technically possible to define and call such a function in Selenium Java? And if so, will the HTML elements on the webpage be visible to this function? The actual website is not shown here because most of it is irrelevant to this question.
Thank you!

Comment: The ajax function is `b.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: !0
            },
            url: pollsL10n.ajax_url,
            data: "action=polls&view=process&poll_id=" + poll_id + "&poll_" + poll_id + "=" + poll_answer_id + "&poll_" + poll_id + "_nonce=" + poll_nonce,
            cache: !1,
            success: poll_process_success
        })`

Comment: First thing you should do in unminify the JS. It's "unreadable" because it's minified to reduce download time. See http://unminify.com/

Comment: @daddygames Just unminified the JS. Thank you!

Comment: Great point @daddygames !!!

Comment: @daddygames Hey, I just found exact same source code, but formatted properly. I editted it into my post. Could you tell me how to shorten this function so that when I call poll_vote, all it does is sending data to JQuery? (The poll_id and poll_answer_id are both known values, and it would be even better if the function doesn't load pages(so I can call the same function on this page without refreshing browser)). I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
function pollvote() {
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
poll_nonce = $('#poll_' + 30 + '_nonce').val();
    $.ajax({type: 'POST', xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}, url: pollsL10n.ajax_url, data: 'action=polls&view=process&poll_id=' + 30 + '&poll_' + 30 + '=' + 121 + '&poll_' + 30 + '_nonce=' + poll_nonce, cache: false, success: pollprocess_success});
});
}
// Poll Process Successfully
function pollprocess_success(data) {
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#polls-' + 30).replaceWith(data);
});
}

while(true){
pollvote();
}
```

This runs pretty well... The only issue is that performance degrades over time.